# How to prevent CreateRecord and Commit from duplicating records in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

i created a simple Controller in Ember.js that purpuse is to add a Person to the store, save it with REST Adapter to server and get the ID and update the row with the ID.

My code looks like this:

```
App.AddPersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  newRecord: function() {
       currentRecord = App.Person.createRecord({name: "Abraham"});
       this.set('content', currentRecord );
  }
  save : function() {
      var result = this.get('store').commit();
      this.transitionToRoute('people.list');
      return result;
  }
});
```

I call newRecord() and new record is created with Abraham. Next, i allow user to edit the name. After he pushes save i call save function from template this way:

```
{{action save on="submit"}}
```

New record is saved to database correctly as a one row. User is redirected to people list. But suddenly it appears that on the people list Abraham is duplicated.

I've investigated the Store and there are two rows with the same data and the same ID. Userid is different. In database there is only one row.

So how to prevent duplicating added row by Ember.js in this case scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're looking for a detailed canonical answer I'm going to assume that you want to do things "The Ember Way".

Let's assume that this is your `Person` model:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName : DS.attr('string'),
  lastName  : DS.attr('string')
});
```

Generally you'll want to use the `model` hook of your `Route` to set up the content for your controller.

```
App.AddPersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model : function(){
    return this.store.createRecord('person',{
      firstName : 'fake', 
      lastName : 'name'
    });
  }
});
```

Then in your `Controller` you can just retrieve the `content` object, call `save`, and then transition to where you want to go.

```
App.AddPersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions : {
    save : function(){
      this.get('model').save();
      this.transitionToRoute('index');
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a JSBin showing this in action using the `FixtureController` : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1201/edit

Answer (score 1):

Because the record is never in the store. You should actually be getting an error doing this.

The proper way to create a new record is

```
currentRecord = this.store.createRecord('person');
```

Then to save that record out:

```
currentRecord.save();
```